# SQL left join giving duplicate results

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a schema where I have images, and I also have results for those images. The results live in N tables, with different schemas. I need to write a search query that can return me all images, and their results, that match some conditions (including limit and offset).

An image may have 10 results (2 classification, 8 detection). I want the limit to act on the images, and not the results. So, I would expect to get back 10 rows, for 1 image.

Here is what I have so far. The issue with it is the duplication and combining of result rows. I.e. I would expect a row for each result, and not have detection and classification combined like that. Do I need a UNION ALL or something?

```
CREATE TABLE images (
  id         VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE image_results_classification (
  image_id    VARCHAR(40)          NOT NULL,
  c_confidence  REAL                 NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (image_id)  REFERENCES images(id)
);

CREATE TABLE image_results_detection (
  image_id    VARCHAR(40)          NOT NULL,
  d_confidence  REAL                 NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (image_id)  REFERENCES images(id)
);

INSERT INTO images (id) VALUES ('123');
INSERT INTO images (id) VALUES ('456');

INSERT INTO image_results_classification (image_id, c_confidence) VALUES ('123', 0.9);
INSERT INTO image_results_classification (image_id, c_confidence) VALUES ('123', 0.8);
INSERT INTO image_results_classification (image_id, c_confidence) VALUES ('456', 0.7);

INSERT INTO image_results_detection (image_id, d_confidence) VALUES ('123', 0.1);
INSERT INTO image_results_detection (image_id, d_confidence) VALUES ('123', 0.2);
INSERT INTO image_results_detection (image_id, d_confidence) VALUES ('456', 0.3);
```

This schema is contrived for this question to help simplify: there are many more rows on both result tables, and they differ too (not just confidence).

What I want to end up with in my app layer is something like the type:
    Map[Image, (List[ClassificationResult], List[DetectionResult])]

I.e. images, and all there results. **A result set with nulls would be fine.** Perhaps something like this?:

```
id   c_confidence d_confidence
123  0.9          NULL
123  0.8          NULL
123  NULL         0.1
123  NULL         0.2
456  0.7          NULL
456  NULL         0.3
```

This is the query from DB Fiddle:

```
SELECT *
FROM images INNER JOIN
     (SELECT id FROM images LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
     ) AS i
     ON (images.id = i.id) OUTER LEFT JOIN 
     image_results_classification c
     ON (images.id = c.image_id) OUTER LEFT JOIN 
     image_results_detection d
     ON (images.id = d.image_id);
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tuDxwY7kQGfEvZSzaajESG/0

**Edit: There's a secondary requirement where I need to filter on results, and be able to limit and offset on images.**

I want to be able to perform a query like:

> Give me all images AND all their results, that have a c_confidence >
>   0.5. I.e. if an image has a c_confidence of 0.4, then that image (and none of it's results) should be included. If it has a c_confidence of
>   0.6, then return ALL it's results (including the image_results_detection).

I've updated my fiddle to reflect this:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tuDxwY7kQGfEvZSzaajESG/1

In the fiddle, I want no results to come back in, because the image does not have an image_results_classification with confidence > 0.8

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Not used SO in a while

Comment: You say you want to limit images, not results. And this is what your query does. You show up to ten images (arbitrarily picked) along with their results. As your example in db-fiddle contains less than ten images, you show all. What is the problem with that?

Comment: I'm getting the same classification and detection confidences twice. I.e. 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8. I.e. they are sort of cross joining together (not sure right terminology). Does that make sense?

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra: As I wrote in my answer you get every combination of `(0.1, 0.2)` and `(0.8, 0.9)`, 2*2=4 rows. If you got  `(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4)` and `(0.7, 0.8, 0.9)` you'll get 4*3=12 rows.

Comment: can you edit question with expected result

Comment: @PranayRana Yeah, have done.

Comment: Now your expected result looks like a UNION. What do you expect when there's no row in both classification and detection for a given id?

Comment: @dnoeth Right. In that case, for the image components to be returned (just the id in this case, but in my real code there's metadata attached to an image). I basically want the images and there corresponding results.

Comment: @LukStorms query is probably the best when you want to limit the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can GROUP_CONCAT together with a GROUP BY.
The first group_concat can be done in a sub-query with a LIMIT.
To avoid that cartesian join effect between those 2 one-to-many relationships.

**For example:**

```
SELECT 
 q.*,  
 group_concat(d.d_confidence) as d_confidence_list
FROM
(
    SELECT i.id, group_concat(c.c_confidence) as c_confidence_list
    FROM images i
    LEFT JOIN image_results_classification c ON (c.image_id = i.id)
    GROUP BY i.id
    LIMIT 10
) q
LEFT JOIN image_results_detection d ON (d.image_id = q.id)
GROUP BY q.id, q.c_confidence_list
```

Or you could use a DISTINCT by value and do it without subquery

```
SELECT 
 i.id, 
 group_concat(distinct c.c_confidence) as c_confidence_list,
 group_concat(distinct d.d_confidence) as d_confidence_list
FROM images i
LEFT JOIN image_results_classification c ON (c.image_id = i.id)
LEFT JOIN image_results_detection d ON (d.image_id = i.id)
GROUP BY i.id
LIMIT 10
```

But the first method might be faster if there's a lot of confidences in those joined tables.

**Extra**

Here's 2 more queries to try out.

The first one should get that expected result.
Using a CTE, the LIMIT has be done only once.

```
with TOPIMG as (
  select * from images LIMIT 10
)
select image_id, c_confidence, null as d_confidence
from TOPIMG i
join image_results_classification c on c.image_id = i.id
union all
select image_id, null as c_confidence, d_confidence
from TOPIMG i
join image_results_detection d on d.image_id = i.id
order by image_id;
```

And this query uses a trick to mimic the ROW_NUMBER function with PARTITION in a roundabout way.   (I don't like it, it kills performance)

```
with TOPIMG as (
  select * from images LIMIT 10
)
select 
image_id, 
max(case when src = 'c' then conf end) as c_conf,
max(case when src = 'd' then conf end) as d_conf
from 
(
  select image_id, 'c' as src, c_confidence as conf,
  (
    select count(*) 
    from image_results_classification c2 
    where c.image_id = c2.image_id and c.c_confidence >= c2.c_confidence
  ) as RN
  from TOPIMG i
  join image_results_classification c on (c.image_id = i.id)

  union all

  select image_id, 'd', d_confidence,
  (
    select count(*) 
    from image_results_detection d2 
    where d.image_id = d2.image_id and d.d_confidence >= d2.d_confidence
  ) as RN
  from TOPIMG i
  join image_results_detection d on (d.image_id = i.id)
) cd
group by image_id, RN
order by image_id, RN;
```

**UPDATE**

**Implementing the special sauce `c_confidence > 0.5` requirement:**

```
with IMG as (
  select i.id as image_id, 
  max(case when c.image_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as show_all
  from images i
  left join image_results_classification c on (c.image_id = i.id and c.c_confidence > 0.5)
  group by i.id
  order by i.id
  LIMIT 100
)
select c.image_id, 'c' as result_type, c.c_confidence as confidence
from IMG i
join image_results_classification c on c.image_id = i.image_id
where i.show_all = 1

union all

select d.image_id, 'd' as result_type, d.d_confidence as confidence
from IMG i
join image_results_detection d on d.image_id = i.image_id
where i.show_all = 1

union all

select i.image_id, null, null
from IMG i
where i.show_all = 0

order by image_id;
```

Comment: This works. I didn't know about group_concat. I'll leave the question open for now, but this could work. The issue I see is that I actually have many more rows besides confidence on the result tables. I think i'd prefer a flatter structure

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra Well, I've added an alternative that seems to give the same results.

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra had some fun with the trying out the limitations of SqlLite.  2 more queries were added.

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra Btw, normally when using a LIMIT then an ORDER BY would be added.  With just the sample records it doesn't matter, but with more data normally you'd want to return the TOP x of something.  Without an ORDER BY you'd just get a random TOP x records. Just thought I should mention that.

Comment: Yeah absolutely. In my actual code, I have an order by. I'm integrating this query today, so I'll let you know if I have any more difficulties. Thanks, I really appreciate it

Comment: Hmm, this query doesn't quite work for me. I omitted some detail from the question. I need to be able to perform conditionals on the results (i.e. return me all images where the c_confidence is > 0.9), and receive ALL the results for the images that have a result matching that condition. I've updated my question and db-fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You are combining each classification with each detection. But the two are not really related, so don't do that. One solution is to select classifications and detections separately and `union all` them.

```
select *
from
(
  select 'Classification' as what, image_id, c_confidence as value
  from image_results_classification
  union all
  select 'Detection' as what, image_id, d_confidence as value
  from image_results_detection
) results
where image_id in
(
  select id
  from images
  -- order by something to decide which images to pick?
  limit 10
);
```

Output:

```
+ ---------------+----------+-------+
| what           | image_id | value |
+ ---------------+----------+-------+
| Classification | 123      | 0.8   |
| Classification | 123      | 0.9   |
| Detection      | 123      | 0.1   |
| Detection      | 123      | 0.2   |
| Classification | 456      | 0.7   |
| Detection      | 456      | 0.3   |
+ ---------------+----------+-------+
```

DB-fiddle demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fZPMNL7NC8GzwkwHc4strG/0

Comment: Perfect thanks. I'll try this tomorrow morning, thank you